# Changing variable in Lambda layer in pretrained model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have imported and pytorch model to keras using pytorch2keras and have made the input flexible from [None,3,224,224] to [None,3,224,224]. Unfortunately, in the original model there is a Lambda layer reducing the output of a convolutional layer by 1, e.g. [None,3,111,111] -> [None,3,110, 110].

How can I specify in my config that I would like to do [None,3,None,None] -> [None,3,None-1, None-1]?

The shape of the Lambda layer is hardcoded here (see below line: (3,0,110)):

```
[...,  
{'name': 'lambda_2',
  'class_name': 'Lambda',
  'config': {'name': 'lambda_2',
   'trainable': True,
   'function': ('4wQAAAAAAAAABAAAAAYAAABTAAAAc34AAAB8AWQBawJyFHwAfAJ8A4UCGQBTAHwBZAJrAnIwfABk\nAGQAhQJ8AnwDhQJmAhkAUwB8AWQDawJyUnwAZABkAIUCZABkAIUCfAJ8A4UCZgMZAFMAfAFkBGsC\ncnp8AGQAZACFAmQAZACFAmQAZACFAnwCfAOFAmYEGQBTAGQAUwApBU7pAAAAAOkBAAAA6QIAAADp\nAwAAAKkAKQTaAXjaBGF4aXPaBXN0YXJ02gNlbmRyBQAAAHIFAAAA+j4vdXNyL2xvY2FsL2xpYi9w\neXRob24zLjYvZGlzdC1wYWNrYWdlcy9weXRvcmNoMmtlcmFzL2xheWVycy5wedoMdGFyZ2V0X2xh\neWVypgQAAHMQAAAAAAEIAQwBCAEUAQgBGgEIAQ==\n',
    (3,0,110),
    None),
   'function_type': 'lambda',
   'output_shape': None,
   'output_shape_type': 'raw',
   'arguments': {}},
  'inbound_nodes': [[['lambda_1', 0, 0, {}]]]},
..]
```

Comment: Can you share your model?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to replace the function with `lambda x: x[:,:,:-1,:-1]`. (If you decide later to use channels_last, then `lambda x: x[:,:-1, :-1]`.

No sure what to do with the argument `(3,0,110)`, but it seems unnecessary.